# Save Custom Layout in Blender 2.67b?

Tags: interface, customization

**How can I save my custom layout** in Blender 2.67b?

Changing the name of the default layout, clicking the plus-sign to the right of it, and "Save User Settings" in *User Preferences* all don't work!

Is this a bug? (because all the above does work in previous versions of Blender).

Comment: If the answer was what you want, please accept it. If no, comment about why.

Answer (score 19):

The User preferences such as addons have been [separated from the startup .blend in Blender 2.66](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.66/Usability#Split_User_Preferences_and_Startup_File)

So as of Blender 2.66 clicking "save user settings" in the *User Preferences* menu will **only** save settings such as enabled addons, themes, shortcuts/hotkeys, etc..

- To save the current blendfile (includes layout(s)/materals/models/settings etc.. Pretty much everything.)  as the startup .blend, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and click "save startup .blend" (Note that this **includes** *User Preference* settings)
- To save a different screen layout so it is accessible in the selector at the top of the window,

  [image]

  Press the <kbd>**+**</kbd> to the right of the drop down selector, Arrange the screen the way you want it, then name it whatever you want. (Note that to have it defaulted when you start Blender you then have to save the startup .blend (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>)

Comment: What if I want my custom layout settings be available in any blend file I open? Not just in startup file. And I mean available only as an option in list, not as current layout.

Comment: @PawełAudionysos Not something that can be accomplished easily, as far as I'm aware.. You might be able to write an addon which checks for the desired screen (and appends it if it's not present).

Answer (score -1):

It is possible. Check this out  https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/app_templates.html *application templates.
I need help to configure that .py file to register and unregister the workspace and the splash screen.