# How to restore cloth presets?

Tags: cloth-simulation

Is there anyway to restore the Blender default Cloth settings?
Or is there anyway to find what the default settings are?

I didn't realize at the time that by changing the values I was overriding the default values.

Using Blender v2.76.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That worked -- it restored the default values. For some reason I though they were overriden, apparently they are not overriden permanetly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To restore default settings of presets choose them again from the dropdown list (this can be done not only for cloth presets, but for other presets as well). Note that any already made changes will be lost.

[image: restoring cloth preset image]

This won't work if you changed any preset settings and then [saved your User Preferences](https://www.blender.org/manual/fr/preferences/introduction.html#save-the-new-preferences); new settings will overwrite default ones.          Note that [preferences were separated from startup file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/save-custom-layout-in-blender-2-67b).

---

If attempting to restore cloth preset after its deletion most likely you will need to install Blender once more (if you haven't saved backup of .py files with settings before deleting them) because file is being deleted as you press 'minus' button.

Comment: This is new to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can find it on official mirror

[github](https://github.com/blender/blender/tree/master/release/scripts/presets/cloth)

As [cegaton](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/1853/cegaton) mentioned, put the following files under **/blender/*blender version*/scripts/presets/cloth/** folder

cotton.py

```py
import bpy
bpy.context.cloth.settings.quality = 5
bpy.context.cloth.settings.mass = 0.300
bpy.context.cloth.settings.tension_stiffness = 15
bpy.context.cloth.settings.compression_stiffness = 15
bpy.context.cloth.settings.shear_stiffness = 15
bpy.context.cloth.settings.bending_stiffness = 0.500
bpy.context.cloth.settings.tension_damping = 5
bpy.context.cloth.settings.compression_damping = 5
bpy.context.cloth.settings.shear_damping = 5
bpy.context.cloth.settings.air_damping = 1.000
```

denim.py

```py
import bpy
bpy.context.cloth.settings.quality = 12
bpy.context.cloth.settings.mass = 1
bpy.context.cloth.settings.tension_stiffness = 40
bpy.context.cloth.settings.compression_stiffness = 40
bpy.context.cloth.settings.shear_stiffness = 40
bpy.context.cloth.settings.bending_stiffness = 10
bpy.context.cloth.settings.tension_damping = 25
bpy.context.cloth.settings.compression_damping = 25
bpy.context.cloth.settings.shear_damping = 25
bpy.context.cloth.settings.air_damping = 1
```

leather.py

```py
import bpy
bpy.context.cloth.settings.quality = 15
bpy.context.cloth.settings.mass = 0.4
bpy.context.cloth.settings.tension_stiffness = 80
bpy.context.cloth.settings.compression_stiffness = 80
bpy.context.cloth.settings.shear_stiffness = 80
bpy.context.cloth.settings.bending_stiffness = 150
bpy.context.cloth.settings.tension_damping = 25
bpy.context.cloth.settings.compression_damping = 25
bpy.context.cloth.settings.shear_damping = 25
bpy.context.cloth.settings.air_damping = 1
```

rubber.py

```py
import bpy
bpy.context.cloth.settings.quality = 7
bpy.context.cloth.settings.mass = 3
bpy.context.cloth.settings.tension_stiffness = 15
bpy.context.cloth.settings.compression_stiffness = 15
bpy.context.cloth.settings.shear_stiffness = 15
bpy.context.cloth.settings.bending_stiffness = 25
bpy.context.cloth.settings.tension_damping = 25
bpy.context.cloth.settings.compression_damping = 25
bpy.context.cloth.settings.shear_damping = 25
bpy.context.cloth.settings.air_damping = 1
```

silk.py

```py
import bpy
bpy.context.cloth.settings.quality = 5
bpy.context.cloth.settings.mass = 0.150
bpy.context.cloth.settings.tension_stiffness = 5
bpy.context.cloth.settings.compression_stiffness = 5
bpy.context.cloth.settings.shear_stiffness = 5
bpy.context.cloth.settings.bending_stiffness = 0.05
bpy.context.cloth.settings.tension_damping = 0
bpy.context.cloth.settings.compression_damping = 0
bpy.context.cloth.settings.shear_damping = 0
bpy.context.cloth.settings.air_damping = 1
```

Comment: I wish I have your brains for understanding codes.

Answer (score 2):

Cloth presets are just a script placed within the folder where blender is installed

/blender/*blender version*/scripts/presets/cloth/

If you have other versions of blender installed on the same computer just copy the contents of the cloth preset folder to your current version.

If you feel like recreating the scripts, just create a new text document with the code for the preset.

As an example, to create the silk preset create a new text document and type:

```
import bpy

bpy.context.cloth.settings.quality = 5

bpy.context.cloth.settings.mass = 0.150

bpy.context.cloth.settings.structural_stiffness = 5

bpy.context.cloth.settings.bending_stiffness = 0.05

bpy.context.cloth.settings.spring_damping = 0

bpy.context.cloth.settings.air_damping = 1
```

and save the file as:

**silk.py**

The values for other presets are:

> Cotton: Steps 5, Mass 0.3, Structural 15, Bend 0.5, Spring 5
>
> Denim: Steps 12, Mass 1, Structural 40, Bend 10, Spring 25
>
> Leather: Steps 15, Mass 0.4, Structural 80, Bend 150, Spring 25
>
> Rubber: Steps 7, Mass 3, Structural 15, Bend 25, Spring 25

Or just use those values directly on the cloth simulation physics tab and save a new preset using the plus (+) sign on the presets.