# Save UI panels by project?

Tags: customization

Can you save a custom UI panels layout by project only and not have it as the default when you open Blender?

Comment: Which panels do you mean ? By default if you open .blend with *Load UI* option checked it should load UI arranged as they were. Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/save-custom-layout-in-blender-2-67b

Comment: For example, if you were modeling in a blend file and separate the view into a 3 panel view with two 3d views and an image editor for reference. I didn't know about the load UI being checked, thanks for the help!