# Save window layout instead of startup file?

Tags: customization

How can I save a customized window layout so that every time when I open a .blend file, this window layout is displayed?

Currently, I only know how to `save as startup file`, but apparently this isn't the same as saving window layout.

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/save-custom-layout-in-blender-2-67b. You will need to save startup file if making new layout permanent,

Comment: @MrZak Thanks! But that is still how we save startup file, AFAIK? I wish to have my customized layout when I open any arbitrary .blend file.

Comment: Customized layout will be saved for opening files only if you save it into your startup file. In order to make *your* layout appear while opening file instead of original one first save it into startup file then [untick Load UI](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2151/is-it-possible-to-use-the-startup-blend-ui-layout-in-older-files).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can screen layouts be locked?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34174/can-screen-layouts-be-locked)

Comment: @cegaton You're right! Your answer there has answered this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The window layout(s) of the blender scenes are saved as part of the file. Any file you open will ordinarily open with the window layout with which it was saved, *unless* when you select a file to open in the file browser window, you make certain that the box beside "load UI" in the options pane (customarily to the left of the screen) is unchecked. If you are starting from your default custom startup window arrangement, and unchecked the "load UI" box, the file you load will be in your customized window arrangement. And once you save the file from this arrangement,  when you re-open the file, it will be in your desired window layout.

Answer (score 2):

You can only do that by saving a new startup file. If you want to keep everything but the layout the same, make a new layout, then press ctrl+u to save the startup file. This will only change the layout when you start up any file in blender.

Hope this helps!