# How can I go back to a prior screen layout?

Tags: scene

If I have a screen that looks like this.[image]

and I eventually end up with a screen that looks like this.[image]

How can I get back to the screen first shown above with out starting all over?

Thanks

Comment: you can simply collide upper panels over lower ones and then left over right. eg: see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5631/how-to-close-view-windows

Answer (score 0):

You can easily save your screen layout which allows you to quickly change between the original and your custom layout - see this answer here:

[Save Custom Layout in Blender 2.67b?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/save-custom-layout-in-blender-2-67b)

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply drag the small right triangle at the bottom of the left hand corner of your dope sheet down. Then drag the left hand corner of the 3D view panel down to replace the timeline panel. Once, that is done just pull the corner of the 3D view panel to the right.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Could you upload a picture or animated GIF showing what you mean? This is generally much easier to understand than a set of instructions listed out in text...